How to configure a scenario(s) to start first
How can I configure some scenarios to start first when parallelism is enabled.
Example:
Say I have 12 tests, of which 10 take 10min each and rest 2 tests take 20min each. Runner is configured to run 10 tests in parallel.
If longer tests run first, the overall time take for the tests is lesser, when compared to the case when longer tests are start first.
This seems like a common use-case, but could not find simple way to solve this. Can someone help with this issue.
Thanks in advance.

this is an open feature request, maybe you can contribute code: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2235
